# Creating JSONs in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

In our database we have several tables with a slightly different composition. We would like to build 1 function in postgres that is able to make a JSON out of it with a somewhat specific structure.

Here are two sample tables:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_experience( level 
character varying , value numeric , score 
numeric, mean numeric );

INSERT INTO tmp_experience( level , value , 
score , mean ) VALUES ( 'high' , 0.23 , 30 , 
0.45 ) , ('low' , 0.63 , 45 , 0.56 );

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_gender( level 
character varying , value numeric , 
percentage numeric );

INSERT INTO tmp_gender( level , value , 
percentage ) VALUES ( 'male' , 2.23 , 35 ) , 
('female' , 1.63 , 65  );
```

Below the two JSONs we would like to make:

```
{
  "high": {
    "value": 0.23,
    "score": 30,
    "mean": 0.45
  },
  "low": {
    "value": 0.63,
    "score": 45,
    "mean": 0.56
  }
}

{
  "male": {
    "value": 2.23,
    "score": 35
  },
  "female": {
    "value": 1.63,
    "score": 65
  }
}
```

We would like to have one function in Postgres that can do this. I thought this was relatively simple (and maybe it is!), but I simply cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: So you're combining both rows into 1 json object. What if there are 100 rows, still one object?

Answer (score 0):

Use the aggregate function [`jsonb_object_agg()`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
select jsonb_object_agg(level, to_jsonb(t)- 'level')
from tmp_experience t;

                                            jsonb_object_agg                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"low": {"mean": 0.56, "score": 45, "value": 0.63}, "high": {"mean": 0.45, "score": 30, "value": 0.23}}
(1 row)

select jsonb_object_agg(level, to_jsonb(t)- 'level')
from tmp_gender t

                                     jsonb_object_agg                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"male": {"value": 2.23, "percentage": 35}, "female": {"value": 1.63, "percentage": 65}}
(1 row)
```

UPDATE

You need as many SELECTs as expected levels. You may use derived tables (subqueries in the FROM clause) for nested aggregates:

```
-- jsonb_pretty() not necessary, used for readable output
select jsonb_pretty(jsonb_object_agg(country, levels)) as countries
from (
    select country, jsonb_object_agg(level, to_jsonb(t)- 'country'- 'level') as levels
    from tmp_experience t
    group by country
    ) s
```

or common table expressions:

```
with levels as (
    select country, jsonb_object_agg(level, to_jsonb(t)- 'country'- 'level') as levels
    from tmp_experience t
    group by country
)
select jsonb_pretty(jsonb_object_agg(country, levels)) as countries
from levels;
```

[Working example in rextester.](http://rextester.com/FPA53656)

Comment: Tnx Klin! This works perfectly. One follow-up question: What if we also have a table that has one additional 'level' and you want to make a nested json using jsonb_object_agg, or another postgres function that can do this. Lets say this table (see below)

Comment: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_experience( country varchar , level 
character varying , value numeric , score 
numeric, mean numeric );

INSERT INTO tmp_experience( country , level , value , 
score , mean ) VALUES ( 'DK' , 'high' , 0.299 , 3990 , 
0.49995 ) , ( 'DK' , 'low' , 0.67 , 75 , 7.56 ),
( 'DE' , 'high' , 0.76 , 45 , 
7.45 ) , ( 'DE' , 'low' , 65 , 234 , 8.7 );